# C++ error: invalid use of 'AppleFarmer::AppleFarmer' when ca

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, file-handling

I am getting the error "error: Invalid use of `AppleFarmer::AppleFarmer`. I do not know why I am getting this error since I am not trying to pass any input into my Constructor. Is it possible I have an issue with my .h file? What am i doing wrong to get this error?
I have three different files, and I may also be having an issue with linking the code together as I am doing `#include` for a .cpp file. I am not sure if my code works aside from this error, but I am stuck on this error.

appleFarmerMain.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "appleFarmer.cpp"
int main(){
    AppleFarmer m;
    int harvest;
    int demand;
    m.AppleFarmer();

    while(m.endOfMonth()==false){
        cout<<"Enter a harvest amount:"<<endl;
        cin>>harvest;
        m.harvestApples(harvest);
        cout<<"Enter a demand:"<<endl;
        cin>>demand;
        m.sellApples(demand);
        cout<<"Apple Inventory: "<<m.getInventory()<<endl;
        m.updateCurrentDay();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

appleFarmer.cpp

```
#include "appleFarmer.h"
#include "<iostream>
using namespace std;

AppleFarmer::AppleFarmer(){
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        sales[i]=0;
        harvest[i]=0;
    }
}
bool AppleFarmer::sellApples(int demand){
    if(demand<= inventory){
        sales[currentDay]=demand;
        inventory=inventory-demand;
    }
    else{
        sales[currentDay]=0;
    }

}

void AppleFarmer::harvestApples(int dayHarvest){
    harvest[currentDay]= dayHarvest;
    inventory=inventory+dayHarvest;
}
bool AppleFarmer::endOfMonth(){
    if (currentDay=maxDays){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
int AppleFarmer::updateCurrentDay(){
    currentDay=currentDay+1;
}
int AppleFarmer::getInventory(){
    return inventory;
}
double AppleFarmer::calculateAverageHarvest(){

}
double calculateAverageSales(){

}
void AppleFarmer::printSales(){

}
void AppleFarmer::printHarvest(){

}
```

appleFarmer.h

```
#ifndef APPLEFARMER_H
#define APPLEFARMER_H

class AppleFarmer
{

    public:
        AppleFarmer();
        bool sellApples(int);
        void harvestApples(int);
        bool endOfMonth();
        int updateCurrentDay();
        int getInventory();
        double calculateAverageHarvest();
        double calculateAverageSales();
        void printSales();
        void printHarvest();
    private:
        int sales[30];
        int harvest[30];
        int maxDays = 30;
        int currentDay = 0;
        int inventory = 0;
};

#endif
```

Comment: The comment happens when I try to define the instance m in the AppleFarmer class. in AppleFarmerMain.cpp

Answer (score 6):

In C++ you don't call the constructor on an object. That happens at object creation time. The line

```
m.AppleFarmer();
```

isn't needed. The constructor is implicitly called here:

```
AppleFarmer m;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include appleFarmer.h instead of appleFarmer.cpp because the header file (with .h extension) contains the declaration while the .cpp file contains the implementation.

Then you need also to delete m.AppleFarmer(); because the constructor is called during the declaration (AppleFarmer m text line).